# await is only valid in async function error inside a bot command

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I wrote this code and I can't run my bot, I don't know why.

```
if (command === 'await') {
  let msg = await message.channel.send("Vote!");
  await msg.react(agree);
  await msg.react(disagree);
  const reactions = await msg.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === agree || reaction.emoji.name === disagree, {
    time: 15000
  });
  message.channel.send(`Voting complete! \n\n${agree}: ${reactions.get(agree).count-1}\n${disagree}: ${reactions.get(disagree).count-1}`);
}
```

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it says, await can only be used inside an async function. So if this code is inside a function, make that function async. For example, if the surrounding function looks like this:

```
function doStuff() {
  if(command === 'await'){
    let msg = await message.channel.send("Vote!");
    await msg.react(agree);
    await msg.react(disagree);
    const reactions = await msg.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === agree || reaction.emoji.name === disagree, {time:15000});
    message.channel.send(`Voting complete! \n\n${agree}: ${reactions.get(agree).count-1}\n${disagree}: ${reactions.get(disagree).count-1}`);
  }
}
```

Change it to this:

```
async function doStuff() { // <--- added async
  if(command === 'await'){
    let msg = await message.channel.send("Vote!");
    await msg.react(agree);
    await msg.react(disagree);
    const reactions = await msg.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === agree || reaction.emoji.name === disagree, {time:15000});
    message.channel.send(`Voting complete! \n\n${agree}: ${reactions.get(agree).count-1}\n${disagree}: ${reactions.get(disagree).count-1}`);
  }
}
```

If this code is not in a function (ie, it's at the topmost scope a script), then you'll need to put it in one. It could be an immediately invoked function if desired

```
(async function () {
  if (command === 'await') {
    const msg = await message.channel.send('Vote!');
    await msg.react(agree);
    await msg.react(disagree);
    const reactions = await msg.awaitReactions(reaction => reaction.emoji.name === agree || reaction.emoji.name === disagree, { time: 15000 });
    message.channel.send(`Voting complete! \n\n${agree}: ${reactions.get(agree).count - 1}\n${disagree}: ${reactions.get(disagree).count - 1}`);
  }
})();
```